# NSAttributedString background color rendering iOS 10 VS iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to render a "highlight" natively using NSAttributedString, I'm noticing that it's very pretty on iOS 10, and very boring on iOS 11. 
I could say that the iOS 10 rendering is the correct one.

iOS 10:

[image]

And that iOS 11 is plain wrong, but I guess they decided to sacrifice some drawing calculation for performance reason.

iOS 11:

[image]

I've tried a various settings, but it seems impossible to achieve "easily", meaning not writing any custom String drawing code, to get the iOS 10 rendering on iOS 11.

Comment: Sorry if this feels like a dumb question, but can I know what component is used to display this text? UILabel? UITextView?..

Comment: UILabel, I should try UITextView, but not sure the rendering would differ. Would it?

Comment: Not sure, trying to recreate this, seems to be an interesting problem.

Comment: UITextView def renders text differently than UILabel in iOS 11 with regards to word wrap as it still uses Core Text. You could give it a try. Maybe you will get the old render for your attributed string. If not I have built this type of highlighting using a UITextView and CALayers and I can share the code if switching to a UITextView does not work

Comment: Tried on iOS 12/iOS11 with UITextView, rendering is same as UILabel unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found a reliable solution, and it's actually quite easy. You need to have a `LayoutManager`, so better use a `UITextView` or a custom text drawer of your own. Here is my custom `UITextView` subclass:

```
class QuoteTextView: UITextView, NSLayoutManagerDelegate {

    var highlightColor = UIColor.gl_defaultHighlight

    override var text: String! {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let padding = textContainer.lineFragmentPadding
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -padding, bottom: 0, right: -padding)
        layoutManager.delegate = self
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count)) { (rect1, lineRect, container, range, _) in
            let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: lineRect.origin.x,
                                                 y: lineRect.origin.y - 2,
                                                 width: lineRect.size.width,
                                                 height: lineRect.size.height - 4))
            self.highlightColor.setFill()
            path.fill()
        }
    }

    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager,
                       lineSpacingAfterGlyphAt glyphIndex: Int,
                       withProposedLineFragmentRect rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager,
                       shouldUse action: NSLayoutManager.ControlCharacterAction,
                       forControlCharacterAt charIndex: Int) -> NSLayoutManager.ControlCharacterAction {
        return .lineBreak
    }
}
```